# How to use comparison operators within a SumIfs formula using structured table references

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, comparison-operators, excel-tables

I am trying to use the SUMIFS function to sum all entries in a table that fall between the date ranges specified in another table. I cannot get the comparison operators (">=" or "<") to work. Every variation I make results in an incorrect sum of 0. I have scoured the internet but haven't found an answer.

Here are a couple variations I have tried:

Variation 1:

```
=SUMIFS(tblHoldings[Amount],tblHoldings[Dates],">=[@Dates]",tblHoldings[Dates],"<CurrentHoldings!C4",tblHoldings[Investment],tblCurrentHoldings[[#Headers],[LargeStock]])
```

Variation 2:

```
=SUMIFS(tblHoldings[Amount],tblHoldings[Dates],">="&[@Dates],tblHoldings[Dates],"<"&CurrentHoldings!C4,tblHoldings[Investment],tblCurrentHoldings[[#Headers],[LargeStock]])
```

Other variations have resulted in generic "There-is-a-problem-with-this-formula" error messages. If I remove the comparison operators, the formula will return a sum, so I know the references are correct. I just need to filter those references by date. When I evaluate the Variation 2 formula, the ">="&tblHoldings[Dates] and "<"&tblHoldings[Dates] references evaluate to a #Value error. This seems like it should be a simple formula. What am I overlooking?

Thanks!

Here is a screenshot of the table with the formula (formula returns 0):
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TT5X.png)

Here is a screenshot of the table on the same worksheet as the range table (formula returns correct answer): [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np9ma.png)

Here is the file itself: https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArArDJ7WmD62grkh5Crfi0m3k_m8GQ?e=yb888R

Comment: The references are outside the quotes and concatenated:  `">=" & [@Dates]`

Comment: I have tried that syntax exactly as you are showing it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: When it says it is not a viable formula what part gets highlighted.

Comment: If I remove the ampersand and leave no space between the comparison and the [@Dates] reference, the [@Dates] reference is highlighted. Other variations either highlight the entire formula or nothing.

Comment: Does your Investment column have "LargeStock" entries?  Also, sumifs requires all criteria ranges have the same number of rows.

Comment: Jenn, yes to both.

Comment: Okay, this is interesting. So the table containing the SUMIFS formula and the table being searched are on two different worksheets. When I copied the formula-containing table onto the same sheet as the searched-table, the formula worked. What difference would worksheets have to do with it if I am referencing table names?

Comment: I do need to keep the tables on separate sheets. I'm baffled that the formula would work when the tables are on the same sheet, but not when they are on separate sheets.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your references may be getting mixed up if it works on one worksheet and not the other.  Here is an example of a formula that works perfectly as SUMIFS with multiple tables on multiple sheets.  In this example, arguments are references to structured tables with the exception of the last, which is a static text string.

```
=SUMIFS(t_Claims[f_PaidClaims],t_Claims[f_Month],[@Month],t_Claims[Data Category],"Medical"))
```

Here is another example, but in this scenario, I've swapped out the last critera for a cell value on another worksheet.  Note the single quotation marks around the worksheet name. 'Sheet Name'  I don't see those in your formula.  You can also see that by adding a reference to another worksheet, the references to other columns in the same table (`@[Month]`) have been fully qualified by the table names being added as well `t_DataSummary_ByMonth[@Month]`.

```
=SUMIFS(t_DataSummary_ByMonth[Fixed Costs],t_DataSummary_ByMonth[Month],">="&t_DataSummary_ByMonth[@Month],t_DataSummary_ByMonth[Month],"<"&'Fees - Update Annually'!E269)
```

I suggest highlighting this portion of your formula and remapping it:

```
CurrentHoldings!C4
```

If it should be an absolute cell reference, add the dollar signs:

```
'CurrentHoldings'!$C$4
```

If you are referencing another cell value on another table, such as above, also fully qualify your column references that are in the same table as the formula, especially if the column headers are the same in both tables.

Comment: Thanks @Jenn! That makes sense, and yet as far as I can tell, my references are fully structured: =SUMIFS(tblHoldings[Amount],tblHoldings[Dates],">="&[@Dates],tblHoldings[Dates],"<"&CurrentHoldings!C4,tblHoldings[Investment],tblCurrentHoldings[[#Headers],[LargeStock]])

Comment: Add the table name in front of [@Dates] and add the single quotes to your cell reference CurrentHoldings!C4.

Comment: I did as you said, and Excel automatically drops both the table reference and the single quotes after I press Enter.

Comment: Without seeing your data for addtl insight, the only thing I can think of is to check your columns for text or errors. Those can interfere with sumifs without error handling.

Comment: Here is a copy of the file: https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArArDJ7WmD62grkh5Crfi0m3k_m8GQ?e=yb888R. I appreciate your help!